# Specify application name when connecting to MSSQL from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, connection-string

How can I specify the application name when connecting to Microsoft Sql Server from PHP?

In .Net applications the connection string can specify "application name=XXXX" but I don't see a way to do that in PHP.

We use FreeTDS with mssql_connect.

I have different sources writing to the database and I want to distinguish the sources.

Any ideas are well appreciated.

Comment: It may help if you clarify what library you are using to connect to SQL Server from PHP.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned without knowing exactly what lib you are using it is a bit hard to answer.
However:

Through the ADODB Connection you should be able to achieve using something like:

```
$db = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$dsn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=catalog;Data Source=(local);Application Name=XXXX";
```

Or if you are using PECL PDO_DBLIB >= 0.9.0 it suggests that appname is configurable within the DSN string.

```
$dsn = "mssql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;appname=XXXX";
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php

Hope that helps

Comment: freetds claims to work with PDO dsn: $dsn = "dblib:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;appname=XXXX";

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, and found that php hardcodes the application name to `PHP 5`.

We contributed a patch to add the desired functionality:

[`Bug id: 60124`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60124)